# Do ICC profiles support for different color characteristics for different parts of the image (i.e. near the edges)?

Tags: post-processing, color-management, vignetting

I believe ICC profiles are mostly used for color equalization; and I wonder whether they can be used to correct spatial differences within the images (e.g. vignetting).  I would like to know if the ICC standard supports this, and if so if there are any application to create ICC profiles with spatial information (per-zone characteristic).

Answer (score 6):

No. ICC profiles are only interested in color response (which affects overall contrast too) but nothing spacial.

However, a number of software such as [DxO Optics Pro](http://www.dxo.com/us/photo/dxo_optics_pro/introduction), [Bibble Pro](http://bibblelabs.com/) and [Adobe Photoshop Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/) support *Lens Profiles*. Each software comes with a number of them already made but there is also sometimes a tool to create one of your own. [Here is the one for Lightroom](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/lensprofile_creator/).